# select vs multiple with required attribute behaves inconsistently

Tags: html

I have a basic form like so:

```
<form id="test-form">
<select id="multi" name="mymulti" multiple required>
    <option value="">Choose a different Option</option>
    <option>Foo</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
    <option>Baz</option>
    </select><br>
<select id="single" name="myselect" required>
    <option value="">Choose a different Option</option>
    <option>Foo</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
    <option>Baz</option>
    </select>    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The key point here is two selects, both `required`, but one is `multiple` and the other is not.

If you choose the default options (note you actually have to click on them), and then submit the form, it will tell you that the single select is required, but not the multiple select.

I looked at the relevant portion of the [html5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element), and although there is some talk about how the required select interacts with placeholder elements, I don't see anything about how multiple+required behaves.

The above behaviour is only in Chrome, other browsers seem to behave the same for both types.  My question is, why?  It seems... inconsistent.  I understand how to work around it with some javascript, just not why I would have to?  Can anyone explain the rationale behind this?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KwNb7/) (remember to actually choose the placeholder options).

Comment: Which browsers? Firefox shows me correctly

Comment: If you have multiple options, why would you have a "Choose one"

Comment: Oh boy, yeah... I actually only checked Chrome when I posted this question, but I had noticed it 6 months ago in all browsers

Comment: @Mr.Alien - so only Chrome then... which makes me think it's just a bug.

Comment: @Ryley we are on web, 6 months are too much :P and may be about the chorme, can be a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome is acting right here. While implementation in FF is simply simpel. But chrome's implementation does not only follow the spec, it is also simply logic. If a mutliple or size > 1 select is used, there is no placeholder by definition. And without a selected attribute there is indeed nothing :checked (i.e.: selected) initially.

In case of a single select with size=1. The select > option:first-child with an empty value is the placeholder option. And  a single select has always one option :checked/selected.

Here is a definition of placeholder option in JS: https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/blob/gh-pages/src/shims/form-shim-extend.js#L88-94 and here a definition of valueMissing for select: https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/blob/gh-pages/src/shims/form-shim-extend.js#L128-130

Comment: I think perhaps I misused the word "placeholder"  My point is that if they choose an option with an empty value, regardless of the number of option elements, required+multi should behave the same as required+single shouldn't it?

Comment: No, because a select[multiple] with an empty value option doesn't make sense. This type of control does know the state nothing selected. While a single-select with single-size always has one option selected.